# PHP to check if a URL contains a query string

Tags: php

This is an easy one. There seem to be plenty of solutions to determine if a URL contains a specific key or value, but strangely I can't find a solution for determining if URL does or does not have a query at all.

Using PHP, I simply want to check to see if the current URL has a query string. For example: http://abc.com/xyz/?key=value VS. http://abc.com/xyz/.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For any URL as a string:

```
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY))
```

http://php.net/parse_url

If it's for the URL of the *current request*, simply:

```
if ($_GET)
```

Comment: That worked. I was trying `if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {echo 'has string';} else {echo 'no string';}`with no luck. Thanks!

Comment: Note (to save others some time): 'just' `if ($_GET)` (for the current request) works because an empty array is `false` in a boolean `if($x)` context.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php So indeed no need for `count()` or `empty()`.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is probably to check to see if the `$_GET[]` contains anything at all. This can be done with the `empty()` function as follows:

```
if(empty($_GET)) {
    //No variables are specified in the URL.
    //Do stuff accordingly
    echo "No variables specified in URL...";
} else {
    //Variables are present. Do stuff:
    echo "Hey! Here are all the variables in the URL!\n";
    print_r($_GET);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`parse_url` seems like the logical choice in most cases. However I can't think of a case where '?' in a URL would not denote the start of a query string so for a (very minor) performance increase you could go with

`return strpos($url, '?') !== false;`

Over 1,000,000 iterations the average time for strpos was about 1.6 seconds vs 1.8 for parse_url. That being said, unless your application is checking millions of URLs for query strings I'd go for `parse_url`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

}
```

Comment: You'd think. But when I do a test like `if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
echo 'has string';
} else {echo 'no string';}` I get 'has string' for both of the example urls above.

Comment: There's always a $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] present, regardless if there was a query string in the url. You have to do `if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] !== '') { echo 'has string' }`