# PHP create link using already set url variables

Tags: php, html

i want to create a link like the below:

```
<a href="'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?&action=approve&holiday='.$result["sequence"].'">
```

the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` includes any `$_GET` variables already set, but i am not sure whether to put a `?` or `&` after this in the href because `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` could already include a `$_GET` variable therefore it would need `&` and not a `?`

Comment: i cant see where this helps with adding either `?` or `&`

Comment: I think you would have to check $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] content, in order to see if it already contains any GET variables. For example: 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  contains '?') then you use "&" to include your content, if not then you can use "?". Something like that?

Comment: See this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864237/php-to-check-if-a-url-contains-a-query-string

Comment: Use my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it includes '?' or not.

```
$extra = 'action=approve&holiday='.$result["sequence"];
$glue = (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?') === false) '?' : '&';
```

Then, you can use this:

```
 echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. $glue . extra .'">';
```

**But**, if you don't need the current passed parameters in URL, you can use the way @Utkanos said

Comment: Exactly what I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the URL in parts. All of the data you need is contained in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEMA'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'//...
```

PHP_SELF denotes the URI beyond the hostname, e.g. "/foo/bar.htm" in "mydomain.com/foo/bar.htm"

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php